# Dynamically decode objects in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

What's the correct way of decoding a JSON that can either return a value as a string or an array of strings for one of its keys?

```
struct HTTPError : Codable {
var statusCode: Int?
var message: [String]
var error: String?
}
```

I have the above struct that I use, it works if the returned JSON contains an array of strings in the message property but if it's only a single item, the server returns the property as a string.

The error that I get is the generic type mismatch

```
expression unexpectedly raised an error: Swift.DecodingError.typeMismatch(Swift.Array<Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "message", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a string/data instead."
```

I'm not sure how can I manually decode the object based on the response I get from the server.

Thanks!

Comment: If the API returns two different JSON objects consider to decode the JSON into an enum with associated values to get rid of the optionals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a custom `init(from decoder: Decoder) throws`

```
struct HTTPError : Codable {
    var statusCode: Int?
    var message: [String]
    var error: String?
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.statusCode = try container.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .statusCode)
        do{
            //Try the array
            self.message = try container.decode([String].self, forKey: .message)
        }catch{
            //Try the String if neither work throw an error
            self.message = [try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .message)]
        }
        self.error = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .error)
    }
}
```